# Concatenate Arrays -how to concat two dimensional arrays in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following two arrays in JavaScript:

```
var array1=[[6, 12, 18],[7, 13, 19],[6, 12, 18],[7, 13, 19],[6, 12, 18],[6, 12, 18]];
var array2=[0,1,2,3,4,5];
```

How to concat the above arrays such that each element of array2 gets inserted at the end of each array1.
The result should be such that

```
var merge array=[[0, 6, 12, 18],[1, 7, 13, 19],[2, 6, 12, 18],[3, 7, 13, 19],[4, 6, 12, 18],[5, 6, 12, 18]]
```

Comment: Its not concatenation

Comment: In your example you're adding the value of `array2` to the *start*, not the end.

Comment: If Underscore.js is an option, `_.zip` is a good solution

Comment: i just want the values to get inserted in the start of the array.

Comment: The question body says "at the end". You might want to fix that.

Answer (score 3):

```js
var array1=[[6, 12, 18],[7, 13, 19],[6, 12, 18],[7, 13, 19],[6, 12, 18],[6, 12, 18]];
var array2=[0,1,2,3,4,5];

var merged_array = array1.map(function (value, index) {
  value.unshift(array2[index]);
  return value;
});

alert(JSON.stringify(merged_array));
```

Comment: Note that `map` is a relatively recent addition and may not be suitable if you are supporting old IE (9 is the earliest version where this works): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 1):

```
var array1=[[6, 12, 18],[7, 13, 19],[6, 12, 18],[7, 13, 19],[6, 12, 18],[6, 12, 18]];
var array2=[0,1,2,3,4,5];

$.each(array1,function(index,val){
   val.unshift(array2[index]);
});
```

Comment: Good answer, except the example shows the values added to the start, so you should use `unshift` instead of `push`.

Comment: I'd rather not see a jQuery dependence here... I'd prefer seeing an ES5shim dependence (especially given how little of IE8 is out there)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it.  Note this depends on your arrays being of the same length.

```
for (var i = 0; i < array2.length; i++)
{
   array1[i].unshift(array2[i]);
}
```

Comment: See Rory's comment below.